# Are PostgreSQL scroll cursor on views not performant?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to have a scroll cursor retrieve rows from a view in postgresSQL. Before this I used the cursor on the real table to and it worked just fine, but now it simply takes an extremely long time (i.e. it has not completed yet, it is not feasible at this speed) to even retrieve a small number of rows from the table. The only difference I can think of is: The view is based on a join (which is the reason why I started using a view) and the view is in another schema (should not make a difference should it?) Am I understanding views incorrectly? Does the join still have to happen before I can start retrieving rows? Just doing a `SELECT` with a limit clause on the view returns instantaneous though.

My code is simply:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE somecurs SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT text from notmyschema.someview;
FETCH FORWARD 2000 FROM somecurs;
--- does not return ---
```

Comment: I would guess the performance problem is not on the cursor but on the view.

Comment: Not near enough information. See [Slow Query questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions#Guide_to_Asking_Slow_Query_Questions) for what is needed.

Comment: Set up auto_explain to log queries with auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0.  Then open the cursor, don't fetch anything from it, and close the cursor.  This should cause a plan for the query to get logged.  Compare that plan to the plan you get for just selecting from the view directly with the LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good way to debug this:

1. Run `explain analyze %your query%` on a table.
2. Run `explain analyze %your query%` on a view.
3. Compare those, maybe the view query is missing an index or something.

I highly suggest also using https://explain.depesz.com/ to learn what are the slowest parts of your queries, and how to fix that: each operation like `SeqScan` is clickable and will bring you to an explanation article.

You can also edit your Q with query plans added so people can help you more.